# If variable is in SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to check to see if a variable is in a SQL Table?

For example if I wanted to check if "potato" is in the "veg" table?

```
$search = $_POST['search_input'] (potato)
```

Comment: use WHERE clause , example where vegname ='potato';

Comment: Try to use select query with where condition, if you got result then of course it is in the table, and if did not get the result, it means no row available contain the term you specify in your question.

Comment: Shame that no one picked up that a Potato is a root not a veggie :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mysql_ methods of PHP you can do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM veg WHERE name = 'potato'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('error');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row['num']) {
  echo 'vegetable exists';
}
```

This is just to give you an idea how it works. If you want (and you should, because mysql_ is deprecated) to use PDO or mysqli the query remains the same.

---

**PDO Example**

```
$vegetable = 'potato';
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM veg WHERE name = :name');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $vegetable, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if($row) {
  echo 'vegetable exists';
}
```

Comment: **MySQL_*** is depreciated, you shouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for (to check if a variable is in a table)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

Example

```
CREATE TABLE veg(veg_items CHAR(30));

INSERT INTO veg  VALUES('potato'),('Redish'),('Ginger');

SELECT veg_items FROM veg WHERE veg_items = 'potato';
+-----------+
| veg_items |
+-----------+
| potato    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the potato at the **WHERE** clause:

```
Select * from veg where name='potato';
```

If you want to check the input of someone, use `SELECT * FROM veg WHERE name='$search'`

Beware of **mysql injection** though.

Answer (score 0):

Try PDO Statements for such kind of  queries .. because such queries are more prone to SQL injections.

try below

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT count(*)   FROM veg     WHERE name =:name ');
$sth->execute(array('potato'));
$ret = $sth->fetchAll();
```